# Get pre-processed data from nested Paragraphs

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I am new to Drupal and building a theme with Drupal 8 + PatternLab. Instead of printing the actual paragraphs, I just extract the data from the fields and pass it to the front-end twig modules. For example, I have a "Hero" paragraph with a nested "Video" paragraph. The "Hero" paragraph has a "Title" field and the "Video" paragraph has a "Video URL" field. The "Video URL" field is of type "Media", which would be a reference to an entity. Here is the template for the paragraph:

`// paragraph--hero.html.twig
{%
  include '@organisms/o-hero.twig'
  with {
    title: data.title,
    video_url: ???
  }
%}`

Here is the `THEME.theme`:

```
function THEME_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  foreach ($variables['content'] as $field => $fieldData) {
    if (isset($fieldData['#field_type'])) {
      $newField = preg_replace('/^field_/', '', $field);

      // text
      if (in_array($fieldData['#field_type'], ['string', 'string_long', 'text', 'text_long'])) {
        if ($fieldData['#is_multiple']) {
          $variables['data'][$newField] = array_map(function ($item) {
            return $item['value'];
          }, $fieldData['#items']->getValue());
        } else {
          $variables['data'][$newField] = $fieldData['#items']->getValue()[0]['value'];
        }
      }

      // link
      if (in_array($fieldData['#field_type'], ['link'])) {
        $link = $fieldData[0];
        $title = $link['#title'];
        $url = $link['#url']->toString();
        $target = $link['#options']['attributes']['target'] ?? null;
        // echo '<pre>'; var_dump($link); exit;
        if (!$fieldData['#is_multiple']) {
          $variables['data'][$newField] = [
            'title' => $title ? $title : null,
            'href' => $url ? $url : null,
            'target' => $target ? $target : null
          ];
        }
      }

      // image
      if (in_array($fieldData['#field_type'], ['entity_reference'])) {
        if (!$fieldData['#is_multiple']) {
          if (isset($fieldData[0]['#media']->field_media_image)) {
            $image = $fieldData[0]['#media']->field_media_image;

            $imageUri = $image->entity->uri->value;
            $imageUrl = file_create_url($imageUri);

            $variables['data'][$newField] = [
              'alt' => $image->alt,
              'sizes' => [
                'default' => $imageUrl
              ]
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way I get the `data` variable with only the data I need in the front-end. But the problem is that when using a nested Paragraph, it won't go through the pre-process functions since it's not actually being rendered, only its data are being extracted. Now, I can access the "Video URL" media inside the "Video" paragraph, but it only gives back the Entity ID value, and it doesn't get populated with the actual Entity values so I can extract the video thumbnail / title / url.

I am not sure if I could explain this correctly, but I want to be able to access `content.field_video_paragraph` fields same way I access the main paragraph field `content.field_title`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd advice not to loop through the render array `content`, but go directly for the entity object, in your case `$paragraphObject = $variables['paragraph']`

Once you have the object, you can always query any data you want, to drill through a referenced/nested entity, use `->entity`:
`$paragaph->hostfield->first()->entity->field_whatever->value`

For paragraphs, you can also query upwards:
`$parentEntity = $paragraph->getParentEntity()`

The example above works similar for almost all entity templates like `node.html.twig` or `paragraph.html.twig` and actually wouldn't need any preprocessing at all, since the entity object is passed to Twig:

Most of the time you can use
`entity.fieldname.index.value`

E.g. for a simple plain text field:
`{{ paragraph.field_whatever.0.value }}`

For nested paragraphs or referenced entities you can use:
`{{ paragraph.hostfield.0.target_id }} /* only numeric ID of ref.ent. */`
`{% paragraph.hostfield.0.entity %} /* referenced entity object, can be queried again */`
`{{ paragraph.hostfield.0.entity.field_whatever.0.value }} /* field value of a nested paragraph */`

For your hero paragraph you could do something like

`{% include 'hero.twig' with { title: paragraph.field_title.0.value } %}`